# ASP.NET Core 2.0 webapi application not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, kestrel-http-server

I have a server with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it, here's a `lsb_release -a` output:

[image: lsb_release -a output]

I'm trying to get my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app (webapi) running on this server. My goal is to have a Kestrel server running on a port 8000 so I could call it from any remote host (not only from localhost).

Let me show you what I've done so far:

1. I installed the .net core:

   ```
   curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
   sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
   ```
2. I created an app:

   dotnet new webapi -n webapi
   I got an  error here saying the lock cannot be obtained in some /tmp/... directory but the dotnet new command itself succeeded. I figured it has to be some kind of permissions problem so I applied a `sudo dotnet restore` command inside the project directory and it went all good.
3. I run the application with `dotnet run` and got the message saying `Now listening on http://localhost:5000`.
4. I opened another ssh session and executed `curl -I http://localhost:5000/api/values/` but the response is 404:

[image: 404 response]

I tried changing `app.UseMvc()` in Startup.cs to `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` but it didn't help - I still cannot access my ValuesController.

As you can see, I'm not able to run an out of box application. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to post the code from controller and startup.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a verb GET that matches the routes defined.
By default -I will send a HEAD request.

E.g, for a GET:

```
$ curl -I -X GET http://localhost:5000/api/values/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Ok, I'm embarrassed right now - I guess I didn't pay attention when reading the documentation of curl. Thank you, Bruno.